# Css is not updating,js adding to head or IdoSell Shop

Tags: css, less, content-management-system

I need to change some styles of online shop made by IdoSell Shop cms. I need to do this by writing a custom style file that will be combined with the template's CSS code. This cms also uses Less and the used template is written in Less, but I decided to use CSS.

I want to change some styles via console in the browser and I do it like this:

That's my custom css:

```
.slick-prev, .slick-next {
    display: none;
}

#main_cms2 {
    margin: 0;
}

strong.price {
    color: #e35c5c;
}

@media screen and (max-width:757px)
{
    #main_cms
    {
        display: none;
    }

    #main_hotspot_zone1 h2 {
        padding-top: 1rem;
    }

    #main_hotspot_zone1 h2 .headline {
        padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:375px)
{

    #main_hotspot_zone1 h2 .headline {
        margin-bottom: -25px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:630px)
{
    .footer_banner {
        width: 49.5%;
    }

    .footer_banners {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. The only thing that works is:

```
strong.price {
    color: #e35c5c;
}
```

So I tried to update styles via console to see if that could work. I did this lite that:

```
var css = `.slick-prev, .slick-next {
    display: none;
}

#main_cms2 {
    margin: 0;
}

strong.price {
    color: #e35c5c;
}

@media screen and (max-width:757px)
{
    #main_cms
    {
        display: none;
    }

    #main_hotspot_zone1 h2 {
        padding-top: 1rem;
    }

    #main_hotspot_zone1 h2 .headline {
        padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:375px)
{

    #main_hotspot_zone1 h2 .headline {
        margin-bottom: -25px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:630px)
{
    .footer_banner {
        width: 49.5%;
    }

    .footer_banners {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
}`;

var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var style = document.createElement('style');

head.appendChild(style);

style.type = 'text/css';
if (style.styleSheet){
  // This is required for IE8 and below.
  style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
} else {
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
}
```

It creates `<style>...</style>` tag in the header and this tag contains my css that I specified above. But it doesn't work. The only thing that works is:

```
strong.price {
    color: #e35c5c;
}
```

I really have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: have you imported your css file into the head section of your HTML? Can you link your HTML and it will be easier to find the issue

Comment: It's being handled by that cms, but as you can see I added css to head myself and it still doesn't work.

Comment: It's not best practice which i'm sure people on this website will tell you but test it with the !important property

Comment: No problem, do you mind ticking my answer to close the ticket off? any other issues let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not best practice which i'm sure people on this website will tell you but test it with the !important property after your classes, this will tell you if you are able to change the CSS directly, unless you can find a way to change the current software properties directly which i would recommend doing first

Comment: Unfortunately it seems like the only way.